# Question about change of basis techniques.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation, change-of-basis

Let's say I have a linear transformation $T: V\rightarrow V$ ($V$ finite-dimensional) and I am asked to find $[T]_\beta$, the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis $\beta=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$.

As I understand it, I compute $T(v_j)$ for all $v_j\in\beta$. Then, I set that equal to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}v_i$ and I get a system of linear equations from which I can solve for $a_{ij}$ which are the entries in $[T]_\beta$.

Now, if I want to instead find $[T]_{\beta'}$ (the matrix representation with respect to a new basis), is it true that $[T]_{\beta'}={([id_V]_{\beta'}^{\beta})}^{-1}[T]_\beta [id_V]_{\beta'}^{\beta}$? If not, how to I compute $[T]_{\beta'}$ using my knowledge of $[T_\beta]$?

Comment: Yes you are correct it is $[T]_{\beta'} = [I]_{\beta'\beta}[T]_{\beta}[I]_{\beta\beta'}$. $[T]_\beta$ and $[T]_{\beta'}$ are similar matrices.

Comment: BTW, if you need to find $[T]_\beta$ then you just need to find $T(v_j)$, $T(v_j)$ will be the jth column of $[T]_\beta$ with respect to basis $\beta$ of course.